# How to avoid iOS devices being first selection when launching iPhoto

Tags: ios, photos.app

As an developer I often have an iOS device connected to my MacBook Air when I launch iPhoto.  The standard behaviour is for the last selected item in the source list to be selected on launch, except when a device is connected, in which case iPhoto attempts to show you photos ready to import from the connected device.

How can I get iPhoto to ignore the connected device and just show me last item selected, which in my case is always Photostream since I'm constantly posting screen grabs of app defects?

Answer (score 3):

Iphoto>Preferences>General>Connecting A Camera>Opens No Application.

or

you can do it through the Image Capture application. There is a pane in the lower left where you can change the preferences when the iPhone is connected.

So
1. connect the phone
2. open Image Capture
3. change the settings for the iPhone which is treated as a camera.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the answers, in fact neither solution works, I have both those settings as described.  In Image Capture I have "connecting this iPhone opens _no application_.  Try it yourself, open iPhoto with your device connected and you'll see the source list automatically selects it and displays the its photos, ignoring your previous selection which in my case is always Photo Stream.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there isn't a way of doing this.  Either plugging your phone in after starting iPhoto, or starting it with it plugged in immediately switches to it.  I can't even think of a workaround, so the only advice I can offer you is to file a [feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/) entry suggesting it as unwelcome behaviour.

Comment: This would be more appropriate (the advice on filing a feedback, in particular) as a comment, since you are not providing an answer.

Comment: The answer is effectively 'there isn't a way to do this', it might not be the answer he was looking for, but it's still an answer